# kubernetes stateful set connection

Tags: java, mysql, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I start experiencing with statefulsets, and I'm following this link on kubernetes website

http://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/

How can I connect my java  application to the mysql database statefulset (they are all in same kubernetes cluster node and namesapce)? what service should I connect to ? which address should I use ? 
I tried mysql-read.default.svc.cluster.local:3306 didn't work !!!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. @montatich was the issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was cross-posted to [the Vitess mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vitess/3qIyNpNFUjk/ub3JS4lbFQAJ) and was solved there. It turns out this happened because the user modified the tutorial setup to add a password for the `root` user. As a result, readiness probes that expected password-less login to work were failing, and the `mysql-read` service was left with no valid endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to alter the services as below,

## Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql

### **type: LoadBalancer**

## Client service for connecting to any MySQL instance for reads.

## For writes, you must instead connect to the master: mysql-0.mysql.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-read
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  **type: LoadBalancer**

Hence, you will be having the external ip to connect your mysql master /slave

in command prompt : mysql -uroot -h30.12.11.21 -P3306  (replace host with your loadbalancer ip)

Comment: I tried this approach, Not only connection is unsuccessful but also deployment has been failed.

Comment: I try this the external ip shows pending..